# Dell XPS 15 9570 not touchpad

Tags: touchpad, release-juno, dell

I get a Dell 15" 9570 and I try to install Juno on it but the touchpad doesn't work on liveCD so I install still (with an usb mouse) to try to solve but nothing work.. .

Do you know more about this issue ?

I try lot of stuff e.g : http://pappanyn.me/blog/2017/05/03/ubuntu-and-the-dell-xps-9560-touchpad/

https://medium.com/@peterpang_84917/personal-experience-of-installing-ubuntu-18-04-lts-on-xps-15-9570-3e53b6cfeefe

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0):

I have an XPS 9550 and everything is fine. I would suggest to update to the latest BIOS, 1.9.0 from the Dell website and see if it works.

Comment: Oh ! I try to night and I tell you if this work. Because in the bios menu the touchpad work.

Comment: ps : my bios version is 1.3.0

Comment: Hello again, 
So no the upgrade change nothing with the liveCD. I check time to time if they are a new bios. Thank for the hint.